# KafkaJS producer and consumer working but not showing the Output

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am trying to execute the below producer code in Node JS using kafkajs module

```
const {Kafka} = require("kafkajs")

const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId : 'my-producer',
    brokers : ['kafka1:9092']
})

const producer = kafka.producer();

const produceMessage = async () =>
{
    const value = Math.random() * 1;
    console.log(value);
 try{
  await producer.send({
    topic : 'tester',
    messages : [
        {
            value
        },
    ],
})
 }catch(error)
 {
    console.log(error);
 }
}


const run = async () =>
{
    await producer.connect()
    setInterval(produceMessage,1000)
}

run()
```

And the following consumer code

```
const {Kafka} = require("kafkajs")

const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId : 'my-consumer',
    brokers : ['kafka1:9092']
})

const consumer = kafka.consumer({groupId : 'consumer-group'});
const run = async () => {
await consumer.connect()
await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'tester' })

await consumer.run({
  eachMessage: async ({ topic, message }) => {
    console.log({
      offset: message.offset,
      value: message.value,
    })
  },
})
}


run()
```

But I am not able to see the output which is being sent from producer to consumer. Neither I can see any random numbers being generated by the producer nor any data being fetched by the consumer.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: `kafka1` refers to an external host, or container?

Comment: @OneCricketeer just wanted to know that what is exactly an external container and a container as I am new to Kafka?

Comment: Docker container? In other words, what is broker of `kafka1` ? If you are running Kafka and this code locally, you should use `localhost:9092`

Comment: I tried doing with localhost but the error remains the same...

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. Where is kafka server actually running? Maybe you should add a try catch to `await producer.connect()` to log any connection errors. Same for the consumer. Because if there are Kafka connection errors, then no, you'll never see `console.log(value);`

Comment: I am running kafka on localhost